# not able to connect to localhost in MS SQL Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, localhost, ms-sql

I have installed MS SQL Server Management Studio 2017. After installing, when I try to connect to the local host by typing either "127.0.0.1" or "local" or "." (dot) in the server name field, I get following pop up.
[SQL Server error popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYv07.jpg)

When I tried googling things, I got to know that starting SQL server services in services.msc would solve the problem but when I opened services.msc, I couldn't find any service listed which was related to SQL Server Management Studio.

I am a newbie here. Haven't worked with any such tool before. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Management Studio does not installs SQL Server database engine. You need to install SQL Server also.